# Why am I getting an incorrect input string error when I am trying to make currency calculations? C#

Tags: c#, types

I am trying to create a basic bank teller application where the balance ALWAYS starts out at $1000 and you can deposit and withdraw amounts. Currently, since the balance will always start at $1000, I have

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lblBalance.Text = "1000.00";
        
    }
```

in the initializer, since it will always start out at 1000, and then I have

```
private void btnWithdraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       
        //Withdraw button, initializing variables to make withdrawal calculation based on current balance and what input is in withdrawal text box.

    {
        decimal withdraw = Decimal.Parse(txtWithdraw.Text);
        decimal INaccountBalance = Decimal.Parse(lblBalance.Text);
        decimal FINaccountBalance = (INaccountBalance - withdraw);

        lblBalance.Text = FINaccountBalance.ToString("c");
        
        
    }
```

on the withdraw button click, which is a calculation that just updates the balance based on what the current balance is in the label subtracted by whatever input is put into the text box for withdrawal, however my program crashes if i try to withdraw more than twice. So I can put 1 value in for the withdrawal and it will do the calculation and update the balance, but if I withdraw again it will just crash the program and give me an 'Input string was not in a correct format.' Error.

Comment: What is the label “balance” text updated to after the first time? (It would be better to use a separate variable for the balance, only updating the label from the underlying balance variable; this would entirely eliminate having to convert the balance label text back to a decimal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you can't `Parse` *currency* format:

```
  lblBalance.Text = FINaccountBalance.ToString("c");
```

which returns to `lblBalance.Text` something like

```
  123.00$
```

(note currency sign `$`) and this string can't be `Parse`d again (you have `FormatException` thrown) into `decimal` on

```
  decimal INaccountBalance = Decimal.Parse(lblBalance.Text);
```

You can try *changing* format, say, into `F2` - let the balance be with *two* digits after decimal point

```
  lblBalance.Text = FINaccountBalance.ToString("F2");
```

Now you are going to have decimal representation *without currency signs*

```
  123.00
```

which can be `Parse`d on the next withdrawal

Comment: `$123.00` parses fine for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GVKps

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overload of `Parse` that accepts this

```
decimal INaccountBalance = Decimal.Parse(lblBalance.Text, NumberStyles.Any, null);
```

Or

```cs
decimal INaccountBalance = Decimal.Parse(lblBalance.Text, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, null);
```